# "Additive" glBlendFunc

Tags: opengl

If i have two overlapping triangles, each with gray color (0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1), how would I set up glBlendFunc, such that the overlapping section renders brighter (closer to white) than the non-overlapping sections?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could set up your glBlendFunc like this:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE);
```

This will give you a blend equation where output_color = 1 * source_color + 1 * destination_color.

See also this [documentation](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBlendFunc.xhtml).

Comment: So it turns out that my main problem was the interaction of these blend functions with glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST).  Once I had commented that out, the blending made more sense (I still don't understand why tho).  Anyway, (GL_ONE, GL_ONE) works fine with gray as my question states, but other colors get clipped in strange ways.  I'm having better luck with (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_DST_COLOR) and (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_DST_ALPHA).  Thanks anyway for the pointer and the quick response.